# Filter on original stream if previous filter resulted in an empty stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Looking to come up with a way to apply a filter on the original stream if a previous filter returned an empty stream.  For instance:

- Given a stream of numbers
- Get and return all even numbers
- If none, get and return all numbers that are a multiple of 3
- If none, get and return all numbers that are a multiple of 5
- etc..

A trivial approach to this would be:

```
List<Integer> numbers = ...

List<Integer> filteredNums = numbers.stream()
    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (filteredNums.isEmpty()) {
    filteredNums = numbers.stream()
        .filter(n -> n % 3 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

if (filteredNums.isEmpty()) {
    filteredNums = numbers.stream()
        .filter(n -> n % 5 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Given a list of numbers such as 1, 3, 5, 15, 21, would result in 3,15,21.

My example with numbers is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, but conveys the same concept.  I could create a Collector to do this, but in general I feel there is something simple I'm missing.  Ideally I'd like the solution to be able to be used in a stream so I can continue performing additional stream operations on it.  In this scenario, maybe I'd want to reduce it to a sum or map where I multiple each number and the collect into a list.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a stream with your predicates and filter your collection with each one of them, until the result of the filter operation returns a non empty list:

```
Stream<Predicate<Integer>> predicates = Stream.of(n -> n % 2 == 0,
                                                  n -> n % 3 == 0,
                                                  n -> n % 5 == 0);

List<Integer> filteredNums = predicates.map(
        predicate -> numbers.filter(predicate)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .dropWhile(Collection::isEmpty)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

This transforms each predicate to a filtered list (by applying the current predicate to the original list). Filtered empty lists are dropped, until a predicate produces a non empty list or the predicates are all consumed.

Comment: Nice solution!  Why not just tag on `.orElse(Collections.emptyList())` directly to `findFirst()`and return the actual `List`

Comment: @WJS Sure, why not? Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I wonder what is better, to stream once inside the main stream and collect each of those like yours, or stream twice and collect once like YCF_L's solution.
Also important to note that dropWhile is from Java 9.

Comment: I find it interesting that so many people caveat Java 9 and even 11 features as though it's something new when we're already up to Java 14.  Yet I don't remember the same level of warning about generics after their release in Java 1.5.

Comment: Well there is a big difference in that starting with Java 8, releases were more often and until about 11 didn't introduce major new functionality, so people would skip releases. Also many larger companies are slower to adopt and may only support up to a certain release.

Comment: @SteveW If you are on Java 8, you can use `.filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())` instead of `dropWhile(Collection::isEmpty)`. The result is the same and so is time complexity, though implementation and operation semantics are different

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way where you can combine your conditions :

```
List<Integer> divs = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5);
List<Integer> filteredNums = divs.stream()
        .filter(d -> numbers.stream().anyMatch(n -> n % d == 0))
        .findFirst()
        .map(d -> numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % d == 0).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

---

The idea is to create a list with the dividers that you want to use, and then find the first divider if it is present then filter all the numbers or return an Empty list

Comment: Definitely would work with my specific example, although I should've been more clear in my original question.  I just used that example to keep things simple.  The filter predicate is what changes.  My actual use case is I'm streaming through objects and finding all objects that match a specific filter, if none found, then go onto the next filter.  

I guess I could do something similar to what you have but the list at the top could be a list of predicates.

Comment: @SteveW this is correct, you can pass a list of predicates in your original problem.

Comment: Maybe this could be improved to not stream the numbers twice for each divisor

Comment: @fps that would be ideal if there could only be one stream and one collect.  This answer and the one you provided are the best so far.  Neither are particularly easy to understand at first glance, but they answer the question and are easy to expand beyond the number example I provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Predicate<Integer>> predicates = Arrays.asList(n -> n % 2 == 0,
            n -> n % 3 == 0,
            n -> n % 5 == 0);

    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(11,12,15,4,43);

    List<Integer> integers = predicates.stream()
            .map(p -> numbers.stream().filter(n -> p.test(n)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
            .findFirst().orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```